# Show date format only and keep sorting AZ in MVCContrib Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, mvccontrib

I use the following LINQ to create grid model:

```
...
            var query = from a in GetUser()
                        select new UserModel
                        {
                            ID = a.ID,                            
                            StartDate = a.StartDate,
                            EndDate = a.EndDate,
                            StateName = a.State.StateName,
                            StateID = a.StateID,
                            City = a.City,
                        };
            return query;
  ....
```

and the HTML is

```
 @Html.Grid(Model.PagedList).Columns(
                        col =>
                        {
                            col.For(c => c.StateName).Named("State").Attributes(@class => "row").HeaderAttributes(@class => "head");
                            col.For(c => c.City).Named("City").Attributes(@class => "row").HeaderAttributes(@class => "head");
                            col.For(c => c.StartDate).Named("Start Date").Attributes(@class => "row").HeaderAttributes(@class => "head");
                            col.For(c => c.EndDate).Named("End Date").Attributes(@class => "row").HeaderAttributes(@class => "head");
                            col.For(c => Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = c.ID })).Named("View Details").HeaderAttributes(@class => "head").DoNotEncode();
                        }).Sort(Model.GridSortOptions).Attributes(@class => "grid")
```

**The main problem is how to show only DATE without TIME part?**

I tried some options but in some cases I got the errors and in other cases sorting AZ doesn't work at all.

Any clue?
Thank you!!!

Comment: try to look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679352/converting-datetime-format-using-razor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
col
.For(c => c.EndDate.ToLongDateString())
.Named("End Date")
.Attributes(@class => "row")
.HeaderAttributes(@class => "head");
```

Answer (score 3):

Something a little easier I find is the **Format** method on the column. [see docs here](https://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid)

So your code looks something like this:

```
col.For(c => c.EndDate).Format("{0:d"})
//use .Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") to get 2014-10-21
```

If you want to use **ToShortDateString** then you will need to define the column name as well as the  sort column name, for example:

```
 col.For(c => c.EndDate.ToShortDateString())
    .Named("End Date")
    .SortColumnName("EndDate");
```