# Razor syntax for view models of type IEnumerable<T> for DisplayFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am pulling a date time from SQL db in the format `hh:mm dd/mm/yyyy`

Using Razor Syntax, I can display the date as stored in DB with

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Updated)
```

I wish for Razor to display in the following format `dd MMM yyyy` So I tried the following as per another StackOverflow answer:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Updated.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"))
```

[Converting DateTime format using razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679352/converting-datetime-format-using-razor)

However this generates the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be
>   used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array
>   index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 36:          Line 37:          Line 38:
>   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Updated.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"))
>   Line 39:          Line 40:

I am just getting to grips with ASP.NET etc... and I am not certain how to create a view model to try this example because I am building DB first with an auto generated edmx file:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")] 
pubilc DateTime Updated { get; set }
```

Any suggestions?

These work at present. All that I want to do is change the display format of the 'updated' property.
My view file:
http://pastebin.com/Ywn8Z0TV

My Controller:
http://pastebin.com/1jAih6AE

My Model:
http://pastebin.com/UC61QjFZ

UPDATE: For those of you stating that should be item => item.Updated...

```
Error   1   A local variable named 'item' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'item', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else
```

Comment: Your lambda expressions are all of the form `modelItem => item.[...]`. Shouldn't you be using `modelItem` on the RHS?

Comment: Hi there, modelItem => modelItem does not work. modelItem =>item is what was scaffolded. It works with modelItem => item. I just need to change the display format

Comment: That sounds *very* odd to me - what variable is `item` referring to at that point?

Comment: Can you edit your post and show the `@model`, the class definition the `@model` uses?  Something is going on that is unusual in the scaffold.

Comment: @Erik - I have included model, view & controller via pastebin above. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically why you solution does not work is exactly as the error states.

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

So `ToString()` is a method and does not work with templates.

Others have already given an alternative soluiton, I wanted to explain why yours didn't work.

> I am just getting to grips with ASP.NET etc... and I am not certain how to create a view model to try this example because I am building DB first with an auto generated edmx file

Your edmx file should create a class that looks similar too:

```
public partial class SomeTable
{
  public DateTime Updated { get; set } 
}
```

In the same project, in the same NameSpace (not necessarily directory) create a file named `SomeTable.Partial.cs` that looks similar too:

```
public partial class SomeTable
{
  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")] 
  pubilc DateTime Updated { get; set } 
}
```

Entity Framework by default creates [Partial Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that represent the tables you've selected.  This means you can define another partial class in another file and .Net will combine all the attributes on each property into a single property when compiled.

**Update**

This code looks odd to me, I don't see how it could possibly work:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Metal.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Currency.Code)
```

**Update 2**

`DisplayFor` is used to display properties on your model (and only properties on the model directly).  When you enumerate through a model of type `IEnumerable<>` (or a property on the model), you can no longer use `DisplayFor` to display those values.  You should be using [`Display`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee292038%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) instead.  For example, `Metal.Name` does not exist on `IEnumerable`, it exists within an element in the `IEnumerable`.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.Display(item.Metal.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.Display(item.Currency.Code)
```

**Error Update**

> Error   1   A local variable named 'item' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'item', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

When code exists like the following:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) // or Model.Items
{
  <div>
  @Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Updated)
  </div>
}
```

All MVC `EditFor` and `DisplayFor` methods use an `Expression<TDelegate>` so when the code states `DisplayFor(item => item.Updated)` the first `item` is basically defining a variable `T item` however you can't define the same variable name again.  To show how this is not MVC specific this will also not compile and give the same error (and is more obvious as to the declaration of the same variable name):

```
var item = 1;
var items = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4};
var sameItem = items.Select(item => item == item);
```

Comment: Hi Erik... This is very strange, and not helping me learn ASP.NET!!! I guarantee you that it works. What's more, ALL my index.cshtml views are scaffolded like that... 'modelItem => item.Property'. The scaffolder displays labels differently though... '        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Metal.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>'

Comment: If i change to what you say it should look like... Error 1 A local variable named 'item' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'item', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: Regarding the partial class with Data Annotations -- this is an approach that I'm working with that seems to be a successful solution thus far.  This blog post is relevant to the discussion and helped to further my understanding [Ardalis - EF Partials](http://ardalis.com/adding-attributes-to-generated-classes)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MM yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I create a viewModel for this when I am doing DB first with autogenerated db model?

Comment: Is your model class auto generated for you by LINQ, Entity Framework, etc? If yes, then those are partial classes. You can add your own partial class to extend the DB generated class, and attach MetadataType annotation to this class, and create class strictly for the metadata for your model. This is done all the time. See this link for an example: http://jameschambers.com/blog/automatic-generation-of-metadata-buddy-classes

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It seems like you're calling the `DisplayFor` method with incorrect syntax.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Updated)
```

When using lambdas, you need to match the symbol names before and after the `=>` symbol.

You are currently using `modelItem` and `item` which are not the same.

Comment: He's already done that, which uses the default DateTime format when displaying the data.  He wants a different format, though.

Comment: Then he should update his question with the code he's actually using.

Comment: He shows the exact `Html.DisplayFor` near the top of his question.  Then right below it, shows what he tried to do that didn't work.  So both the solutions he tried didn't work, and he is trying to get help.

Comment: Ah, the modelItem/item.  Yes, but it seems that was a mistake when putting the code in his question, as he said it was displaying the `DateTime` fine.  Still leaves him with the issue of the incorrect format being used.

Comment: Thanks Gromer... You get it... modelItem => modelItem does not work. modelItem =>item is what was scaffolded. It works with modelItem => item. I just need to change the display format