# How to format Datetime and datetime2 in C# and SQL to fit my needs

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework, datetime

I'm quite new to this, I'm using MVC view model that has a property with `Datetime` type :

```
namespace FP.WebUI.Models
{
    public class AdminSessionsViewModel
    {
        NewSession _NewSession = new NewSession();
        public NewSession NewSession { get { return _NewSession; } set { _NewSession = value; } }
        public IEnumerable<Sessions> CurrentSessions { get; set; }
    }

    public class NewSession
    {
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want `Date` property to be like this format : **27/05/2013 06:44AM** and the same inside SQL database.

I really don't know how to configure `Date` inside the `NewSession` class to automatically get shown like this inside my Textbox and when mapped back to Entity Framework will be saved inside the database like this.

Here's my entity framework fluent API configuration :

```
namespace FP.Domain.Configurations
{
    public class SessionsConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Sessions>
    {
        public SessionsConfig()
        {
            ToTable("Sessions");
            Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.PhotosCount).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.CoverPhoto).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.Date).HasColumnType("datetime2").HasPrecision(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the value to be a string in your database at all? If it's *not* a string, then the format you happen to see it in when you query the database is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm putting the value in a `readonly` Textbox with `datepicker` jquery plugin attached to it.

Comment: So do the formatting at the C# side - fine. Given that you're using an ORM, you shouldn't need to worry about the database side at all. The very notion of what "format" it's in in the database is a red herring - it's like worrying about whether a number in the database is represented as 0x10 or 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `[DisplayFormat]` attribute to your DateTime property. That should take care of the user interface.
See this answer: [Converting DateTime format using razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679352/converting-datetime-format-using-razor)

```
[Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

You don't need to control how the date time is stored in SQL server - it will be stored as date, not as a string. You can use [`FORMAT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function in T/SQL to format that date in stored procedures etc. If you don't have MSSQL 2012, you can use `DATEPART()` or `CONVERT()` functions.

Comment: I've added these annotations, but sometimes when i select a date using jquery datepicker i get ` The field Date must be a date. ` validation error message.