# How to format dates in MVC 5 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table in my razor code that loops through all of the items in the model and creates a table row for each item. I'm trying to figure out how to format the date to MM/dd/yyyy instead of the default "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" format.

```
<table class="table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contract No</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Expires</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(@item.CompanyName, "ViewContract", new { contractID = @item.ID }) </td>
                <td width="200">@item.ContractNumber</td>
                <td>@item.Description</td>
                <td>@item.ExpireDate</td>
            </tr>
            }
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

I have tried @item.ExpireDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") but it throws an error saying that .ToString does not take an argument.

Comment: Is ExpireDate a nullable DateTime?

Comment: Yes. Additionally I'm using the MVCPagedList NuGet package which requires your model to be passed as a PagedList which is why I'm unable to use an HTML helper

Comment: hope the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679352/converting-datetime-format-using-razor helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using the PagedList NuGet package which makes the Html helper calls a little different. I was able to format the date by specifying the date format in the data model constructor and then using the display helper.

In the data model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0: MM/dd/yyyy}")] 
public Nullable<System.DateTime> ExpireDate { get; set; }
```

In the razor:

```
<table class="table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contract No</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Expires</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(@item.CompanyName, "ViewContract", new { contractID = @item.ID }) </td>
                <td width="200">@item.ContractNumber</td>
                <td>@item.Description</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpireDate)<td>
            </tr>
            }
    </tbody>     </table>
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're using c# 6 features you can use a null-conditional.

`@(item.ExpireDate?.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can also now use

`@item.ExpireDate?.ToShortDateString()` which converts a DateTime value to the "M/d/yyyy" date format

Comment: - error:  Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'DateTime' ?

Comment: C# 6 feature ? @cdonner