# How to convert DateTime to Date in ASP.NET Core (working with database)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I'm working with asp.net core in visual studio 2017

I will need to use C#, MVC, or SQL to solve this

I'm creating a table with a  foreach statement (below)

```
        <table>
           <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Month)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Temperature)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
                    </td>

                </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

and I'm trying to modify this model data to display only the Date.

```
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

How would I do this so that all of my model items are effected?

Here are my controller actions

```
 public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

and

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Data data)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(data);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(data);
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting DateTime format using razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679352/converting-datetime-format-using-razor)

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by _How would I do this so that all of my model items are effected?_

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate your model with `DisplayFormat` attributes:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class DateModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you want to avoid repeating these, you can also use a constant:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class DateModel
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = Constants.DateOnlyFormat)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = Constants.DateOnlyFormat)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

public static class Constants
{
    public const string DateOnlyFormat = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}";
}
```

Comment: How would I display only the Date inside of my form?

Comment: Which form? There is no such thing in your question, you are only displaying values. But in case you want to also apply it for **input** fields, here is how that could be done: `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = DateConstants.DateOnlyFormat, ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Date property of DateTime structure.

```
<td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate.Date.ToString("d"))
</td>
```

For more details refer :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netcore-2.2#System_DateTime_Date
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-2.2

Comment: That would have the side effect that the value isn't a _DateTime_ anymore and therefore could be rendered differently in the browser. This would not matter here, but could matter in a form (using _@Html.EditFor()_)

Comment: How would I display only the Date inside of my form?

Comment: I'd try the _DisplayFormat_ attribute like suggested above